# DBeaver wont accept MYSQL Functions. How can i make this work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

SQL query for Dbeaver. Will not work because of LOCALTIMESTAMP()

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM response
WHERE ssn = 123456999 AND 
      response_date >= DATE_SUB(LOCALTIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY response_date DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support `TOP`.  Use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM response r
WHERE ssn = 123456999 AND 
      response_date >= DATE_SUB(LOCALTIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY response_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

EDIT:

The correct syntax in MS SQL is:

```
SELECT TOP (5) r.* 
FROM response r
WHERE ssn = 123456999 AND 
      response_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY response_date DESC;
```

Comment: Well DBeaver doesn't allow you to use LIMIT

Comment: @KalebB . . . DBeaver is a database tool.  It should allow you to pass any valid SQL into the underlying database.  Do you know what *database* you are using?

Comment: Yes MS SQL. And then I am connecting and viewing through DBeaver

Comment: It Worked. Thank you.